# Alt attribute for SEO recommendation

Tags: seo, html

If I want my site to be no.1 for a particular keyword search, would it harm me or help me if I put `alt="keyword"` in all of the images I have in the site?

Answer (score 4):

It might help you, though probably not nearly as much as you'd like to think.  What's more important is that it would be abuse of what alt text is actually *for*: to serve as a replacement for the image if it doesn't load, and as an accessibility feature for visitors who may be using alternative(eg. screen reader) browsers.
In other words: don't do this.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds spammy. It's keyword-stuffing. Don't do it.

What you should do instead is write good, descriptive alt text for all your images.

Answer (score 1):

It would help you. Alt tags are how search engines know what an image is about, and including them will help your site get ranked higher in **image** searches. If you don't include alt tags, your site will rank lower in **image** searches. If you want to get traffic from google **images** (and other **image** searches), then you should include alt tags.

On an somewhat unrelated note, disabled people can't see images, and having an alt tag would help them know what the image is about (they can read the alt tag). If people who can't see images are reading your site, then you should include alt tags to help them out.

But if you aren't worried about accessibility or **image** searches, then don't bother.

Comment: NOTE: the reason why I made image bold was because I wanted to be 100% sure that nobody thought that I was referring to regular searches. If my bolding of image was annoying to you, I am very sorry.