# Can I use H1 with logo alt text or font size zero if I don't have a good place on the page to show big text?

Tags: seo, technical-seo, alt-attribute, hidden-text, h1

I am wondering what is the best approach in SEO when I don't have a good place for H1 tag for example on my Home Page. I have several H2 tags and a lot of H3 tags but in terms of design I don't have any place for nice H1 tag with keywords etc.

I thought of two solutions:

**Solution 1:**

```
<h1>
  <img src="my_website_logo" alt="My Cool Website | Read here a lot of fun things about various things!">
</h1>
```

**Solution 2:**

```
<h1 class="make_it_0px_with_css">
  My Cool Website | Read here a lot of fun things about various things!
</h1>
```

I searched and it seems that hiding text with css will category my website as "spammy"/"not worthy". Will the trick with my logo alt text work?

Or there is a better solution?

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13170/alt-attribute-for-seo-recommendation

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/98108/does-google-penalise-for-local-keyword-stuffing

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3932/keyword-stuffing-in-seo

Answer (score 2):

While H1 used to be a major ranking factor, this is now no longer the case. Check out this article:

https://www.searchenginejournal.com/h1-headings-for-google/406720/#close

Some of the relevant copy:

*No Magic Ranking Power to an H1 Tag:
John Mueller’s statement expressly says that a site will rank fine without an H1 or with five H1s. That means there is no extra importance given to an H1.
Mueller also stated in another Office-hours Hangout that a page will rank fine if you use an H2 or an H1, that they could be used interchangeably.*

In other words, today, if you can't use an H1, but use an H2, search engines will see that H2 as the main heading, or headings, and will parse the page accordingly.

So in your case, go ahead and use the H2 instead of H1. Remember that it's more important to use HTML elements to describe the content on the page, rather than sticking them anywhere you can just to rank - this technique no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your solutions 1 & 2 (minus the image in 1) look like great candidates for a `<title>` tag.

Henry gives solid advice. Just don't use an `<h1>`.